# On the other side of the curve

Tags: pstricks, pstricks-add

Using pstrick's \pspolylineticks, I would like to put my labels on the other side of the curve using PNormal with polar coordinates as in the example of the pstricks-add documentation.

Adding 180 degrees to the angle should do the (ps)trick but I dont know how to do it.

Any suggestion is welcome. Many thanks in advance.

```
\begin{pspicture}(-1,-1)(10,4)
 \psparametricplot[algebraic]{0}{9}{t^2/9 | sin(t)+1}% 
\pscurvepoints{0}{9}{(t^2)/9 | sin(t)+1}{P}% % make ticks using arc-length metric 
\pspolylineticks[metricInitValue=1,ticksize=-2pt 2pt,Os=1,Ds=.2]{P}{ ds }{1}{56}% 
\pspolylineticks[metricInitValue=1,Os=1,Ds=2]{P}{ ds }{0}{6}%   
\multido{\iA=1+1,\iB=3+2}{5}{\Put{6pt;(PNormal\iA)}(PTick\iA){\tiny \iB}}%
\nodexn{(PTick\iA)+(10pt;{(PNormal\iA)})}{Q}\rput(Q){\tiny \iB}}%   
\multido{\iA=1+1,\iB=3+2}{5}{\uput{6pt}[{(PNormal\iA)}](PTick\iA){\iB}}% 
% ticks at x=1,3,... , start at tick index 0, draw 5 ticks 
% the tick at s=1 has index 0 
% ticks at s=1,2... (increment function = distance) 
\end{pspicture}
```

Comment: give an example.

Comment: The example is on page 92 of the pstricks-add documentation v1.75 dated septembre the first, 2016.

Comment: For your convenience, see the example added in my question

Comment: This example won't compile. (Of course, I added `\documentclass` and all the stuff required to compile usual PSTricks codes.) You may want to specify which additional packages you're using.

Answer (score 1):

Define first the negative `PNormal` by `\AtoB(PNormal\iA)(0,0){Q}`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pstricks-add,multido}
\begin{document}

\begin{pspicture}(-1,-1)(10,4)
\psparametricplot[algebraic]{0}{9}{t^2/9 | sin(t)+1}% 
\pscurvepoints{0}{9}{(t^2)/9 | sin(t)+1}{P}% % make ticks using arc-length metric 
\pspolylineticks[metricInitValue=1,ticksize=-2pt 2pt,Os=1,Ds=.2]{P}{ ds }{1}{56}% 
\pspolylineticks[metricInitValue=1,Os=1,Ds=2]{P}{ ds }{0}{6}%   
\multido{\iA=1+1,\iB=3+2}{5}{\Put{6pt;(PNormal\iA)}(PTick\iA){\tiny \iB}}%  
\end{pspicture}


\begin{pspicture}(-1,-1)(10,4)
\psparametricplot[algebraic]{0}{9}{t^2/9 | sin(t)+1}% 
\pscurvepoints{0}{9}{(t^2)/9 | sin(t)+1}{P}% % make ticks using arc-length metric 
\pspolylineticks[metricInitValue=1,ticksize=-2pt 2pt,Os=1,Ds=.2]{P}{ ds }{1}{56}% 
\pspolylineticks[metricInitValue=1,Os=1,Ds=2]{P}{ ds }{0}{6}%   
\multido{\iA=1+1,\iB=3+2}{5}{\AtoB(PNormal\iA)(0,0){Q}\Put{6pt;(Q)}(PTick\iA){\tiny \iB}}
\end{pspicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Many thanks Herbert ! I didn't know of this \AtoB function

Comment: For those interested, this function is documented along with many other useful ones in a pst-node documentation (v.1.33 of march 25, 2014).